# AKS Ingress is not routing properly

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have 2 websites. Each of the site has their corresponding subdomain. To achieve this in AKS, I'm using nginx-ingress to route the traffic according to incoming subdomain.

- testing-web1 - http://web1.testing.com/
- testing-web2 - http://web2.testing.com/
- testing-web1 - by IP address (for testing purpose)

When I enter http://web1.testing.com/, nginx-ingress is routing me to testing-web1. If I enter http://web2.testing.com/, nginx-ingress will route me to testing-web1 instead of testing-web2.

Is this an expected behavior? Did I miss-configure something? I think I'm almost there, but I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Thanks.

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: testing-web1
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: testing-web1
    minReadySeconds: 5 
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: testing-web1
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
        containers:
        - name: testing-web1
          image: image-web1:1.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  ---
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: testing-web2
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: testing-web2
    minReadySeconds: 5 
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: testing-web2
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
        containers:
        - name: testing-web2
          image: image-web2:1.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: testing-web1
    labels:
      app: testing-web1
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
    selector:
      app: testing-web1
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: testing-web2
    labels:
      app: testing-web2
  spec:
    ports:
    - port: 80
    selector:
      app: testing-web2
  ---
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: webapp-ingress
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  spec:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - web1.testing.com
      - web2.testing.com
    rules:
    - host: web1.testing.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: testing-web1
            servicePort: 80
    - host: web2.testing.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: testing-web2
            servicePort: 80
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: testing-web1
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
```

Comment: your 3rd rule masks (overrides) 1st and 2nd rules

Comment: I've test the same yaml you posted and worked for me. I'm using `curl -H "Host: web1/2.testing.com" https://<ingress_ip> -k` to test. The 3rd rule is no overrided here because you passing the host in header. Note you need to test using HTTP... Did you try to test with curl? What is the response?

Comment: @AntonMatsiuk For the 3rd rule, can we specify only IP address? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: @WenHao You can't specify IP in host field. If you leave it blank the ingress will accept requests without "host" header normally. Did you try tests proposed in my first comment?  Test using *HTTPS* and not HTTP (was a mistake in my first comment)